# Could not locate BeanManager from JNDI in Jboss 7

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, jboss7.x, cdi

I am trying to access the BeanManager in Jboss 7.1 through JNDI, but without success. I tried injecting it and directly accessing it from JNDI. I am able to deploy and access the session bean from client.

Below is my code:

```
@Stateless
public class CustomerSessionBean implements ICustomerSessionBean{

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public CustomerSessionBean() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public boolean addCustomer(Customer customer) {
        BeanManager beanManager = null;
        try {
            beanManager = (BeanManager) InitialContext.doLookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Customer: "+customer+"Bean Manager"+beanManager);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the stack trace say? Do yo have beans.xml in the correct location?

Comment: Thank you i misplaced the beans.xml modified it to point to META-INF. Got fixed now thanks alot